# SOAP, WCF, and message signatures

Tags: java, wcf, soap, soap-client

I have a Java (JAX-WS based) SOAP client that I'm trying to get to talk with a (third-party) WCF-based server.  I'm finding the [sentiment expressed here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/147310/25520) to be quite accurate.  But the goal still remains.

So long story short, I can coax a valid "security context token" out of the server, but am getting hung up on message-signing issues (I believe).

The server appears to expect the message to be signed using an `hmac-sha1` authentication code using client/server secret keys (`PSHA1` algorithm).  Fair enough.  However JAX-WS appears to want to use `rsa-sha1` and an X509 certificate to sign the outbound messages (which the server doesn't like), and only seems to use `hmac-sha1` if a `UsernameToken` is provided (which the server also doesn't like).

So I'm trying to manually sign the outbound SOAP messages from within a `SOAPHandler` implementation.  The request that the client sends in order to get a security context token looks like this:

```
<t:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
    <t:TokenType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct</t:TokenType>
    <t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType>
    <t:Entropy>
        <t:BinarySecret Type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Nonce">NzM1MDZjYWVkMTEzNDlkNGEyODY0ZDBlMjlkODEyMTM=</t:BinarySecret>
    </t:Entropy>
    <t:KeySize>256</t:KeySize>
</t:RequestSecurityToken>
```

And the token that the server sends back look like this:

```
<t:RequestSecurityTokenResponse xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
    <t:TokenType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct</t:TokenType>
    <t:RequestedSecurityToken>
        <c:SecurityContextToken xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc" u:Id="uuid-106bdbae-76e5-4195-b5d0-cc1c1a7a813e-13">
            <c:Identifier>urn:uuid:c0be4929-da8d-4955-8e13-b25aa7a37217</c:Identifier>
        </c:SecurityContextToken>
    </t:RequestedSecurityToken>
    <t:RequestedAttachedReference>
        <o:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <o:Reference ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct" URI="#uuid-106bdbae-76e5-4195-b5d0-cc1c1a7a813e-13" />
        </o:SecurityTokenReference>
    </t:RequestedAttachedReference>
    <t:RequestedUnattachedReference>
        <o:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <o:Reference URI="urn:uuid:c0be4929-da8d-4955-8e13-b25aa7a37217" ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct" />
        </o:SecurityTokenReference>
    </t:RequestedUnattachedReference>
    <t:RequestedProofToken>
        <t:ComputedKey>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/CK/PSHA1</t:ComputedKey>
    </t:RequestedProofToken>
    <t:Entropy>
        <t:BinarySecret u:Id="uuid-106bdbae-76e5-4195-b5d0-cc1c1a7a813e-14" Type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Nonce">dssunihZGy2dnnDHV9PMe3vU3lg/kKKZQkFohvGvCAk=</t:BinarySecret>
    </t:Entropy>
    <t:Lifetime>
        <u:Created>2016-04-08T04:11:54.392Z</u:Created>
        <u:Expires>2016-04-08T19:11:54.392Z</u:Expires>
    </t:Lifetime>
    <t:KeySize>256</t:KeySize>
</t:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
```

I'm combining the client and the server `BinarySecret` keys using `PSHA1` as follows:

```
private byte[] getSharedKey() {
    try {
        //FIXME:  client key first, or server key first?
        P_SHA1 algo = new P_SHA1();
        return algo.createKey(getBinaryClientEntropy(), getBinaryServerEntropy(), 0, getSharedKeySize() / 8);
    }
    catch (Throwable e) {
        LOG.error("Unable to compute shared key!", e);
    }

    return null;

}
```

I'm then using that key to compute a MAC for the message, like:

```
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(getSharedKey(), "HmacSHA1");
mac.init(key);

byte[] signatureBytes = mac.doFinal(content);
String signature = Base64.encodeBytes(signatureBytes);
```

That then goes into the outbound requests (along with a ton of other boilerplate things), as the `SignatureValue`.  Ultimately I end up with something like:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <S:Header xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:scon="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc" xmlns:sec="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <sec:Security xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" env:mustUnderstand="true">
            <scon:SecurityContextToken xmlns:util="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" util:Id="uuid-106bdbae-76e5-4195-b5d0-cc1c1a7a813e-55">
                <scon:Identifier>urn:uuid:3ab0f3fb-edd4-4880-af77-d700dda371bb</scon:Identifier>
            </scon:SecurityContextToken>
            <sig:Signature xmlns:sig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <sig:SignedInfo>
                    <sig:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                    <sig:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#hmac-sha1" />
                </sig:SignedInfo>
                <sig:SignatureValue>ohqViTbUYBG2E3hLldUA1AsPBJM=</sig:SignatureValue>
                <sig:KeyInfo>
                    <sec:SecurityTokenReference>
                        <sec:Reference URI="#uuid-106bdbae-76e5-4195-b5d0-cc1c1a7a813e-55" ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct" />
                    </sec:SecurityTokenReference>
                </sig:KeyInfo>
            </sig:Signature>
        </sec:Security>
    </S:Header>
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:HelloWorld xmlns:ns2="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
            <ns2:name>Test</ns2:name>
        </ns2:HelloWorld>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

That leads to "An error occurred when verifying security for the message" responses coming back from the server.

Using wcf-storm to fire off requests and Fiddler2 to inspect the outgoing packets, I know that that I should be close.  The following request works correctly:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <S:Header xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:scon="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc" xmlns:sec="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:mustUnderstand="1">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
                <u:Created>2016-04-05T23:48:06.110Z</u:Created>
                <u:Expires>2016-04-05T23:53:06.110Z</u:Expires>
            </u:Timestamp>
            <c:SecurityContextToken xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc" u:Id="uuid-8085da33-b25c-4f09-b5a9-110635a3ae39-2005">
                <c:Identifier>urn:uuid:91349027-cb32-4c46-9f16-74a6bcb11126</c:Identifier>
            </c:SecurityContextToken>
            <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <SignedInfo>
                    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#hmac-sha1" />
                    <Reference URI="#_0">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                        <DigestValue>AvRXi7pyjulsfdg9afInSFMM+5k=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                </SignedInfo>
                <SignatureValue>TQup7BBN43b8CefrdSRd+X8MBgg=</SignatureValue>
                <KeyInfo>
                    <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                        <o:Reference ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct" URI="#uuid-8085da33-b25c-4f09-b5a9-110635a3ae39-2005" />
                    </o:SecurityTokenReference>
                </KeyInfo>
            </Signature>
        </o:Security>
    </S:Header>
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:HelloWorld xmlns:ns2="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
            <ns2:name>Test</ns2:name>
        </ns2:HelloWorld>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

The main differences are:

- I've omitted the `Timestamp` element (though I've tried including it, and didn't seem to make any difference).
- I've omitted the `SignedInfo/Reference` element, because I'm not sure how its `DigestValue` is meant to be computed.

So after all of that, I suppose the main question is:

**What is the actual algorithm for signing the outbound messages?**  As in, if I have:

```
<Envelope>
    <Header>
        HHH...
    </Header>
    <Body>
        BBB...
    </Body>   
</Envelope>
```

...am I meant to compute the signature value off of `<Envelope>...</Envelope>` (so the entire thing), or just `<Body>...</Body>`, or even just the `BBB...` part?  And if I'm meant to use the entire thing, how do I reconcile that against the fact that adding the signature information to the header alters the content that's used as input when computing the signature?

Is there a more straightforward way to get JAX-WS to generate requests using the required signing conventions that I've overlooked?

And then there are some minor bonus questions:

1. Is there an established standard with respect to which order I pass the client and server `BinarySecret` values when combining them using `PSHA1`?
2. Are the `Timestamp` and `SignedInfo/Reference` entries significant, and if so, what's the correct method for computing the `DigestValue`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After some research and a fair bit of trial and error, I managed to get a working solution.  I'll start with the bonus questions first:

1. I didn't find any formal documentation, and every reference implementation and code sample that I came across always passed the client key first, and this is also what the server (Microsoft IIS v8.5) expects.  So that would appear to be the standard, even if it's not a formal one.
2. Yes, the `Timestamp` and `Reference` values are significant in a big way, and very closely relate back to the main question.

So what's the actual algorithm for signing things in an outbound SOAP message, if you have to do so manually, in Java, using JAX-WS?

[This reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/#sec-CoreValidation) is a helpful place to start, and should give you a pretty good idea of just how overarchitected things have become in the SOAP world.  And some of it is very obtusely described, to boot.  For instance:

> **3.2.2 Signature Validation**
>
> 1. Obtain the keying information from `KeyInfo` or from an external source.
> 2. Obtain the canonical form of the `SignatureMethod` using the
>      `CanonicalizationMethod` and use the result (and previously obtained
>      `KeyInfo`) to confirm the `SignatureValue` over the `SignedInfo` element.

If your `KeyInfo` is a `SecurityTokenReference` to a `SecurityContextToken` that doesn't actually contain any key data itself, and your `SignatureMethod` is `Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#hmac-sha1"`, it's clear as mud how any `CanonicalizationMethod` relates to that or how you're supposed to get from that to knowing that you need to combine the server and client `BinarySecret` values and take the result to be your key.  But I digress.

The algorithm to apply is more-or-less described in the `Signature` block.  For instance, if the server you're talking to expects something like:

```
<o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:mustUnderstand="1">
    <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
        <u:Created>2016-04-11T00:53:44.050Z</u:Created>
        <u:Expires>2016-04-11T00:58:44.050Z</u:Expires>
    </u:Timestamp>
    <c:SecurityContextToken xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc" u:Id="uuid-41b0578e-dc47-4467-9b65-b0cebde98309-1">
        <c:Identifier>urn:uuid:9eba64a2-5cf8-4ea9-85e9-359b2edbb13c</c:Identifier>
    </c:SecurityContextToken>
    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#hmac-sha1" />
            <Reference URI="#_0">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                <DigestValue>CwJgqLNOoHJpuiqIOylvVvFli1E=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>fJxof0blfd6abX0V4EmPYZ/NGJI=</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
            <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                <o:Reference ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct" URI="#uuid-41b0578e-dc47-4467-9b65-b0cebde98309-1" />
            </o:SecurityTokenReference>
        </KeyInfo>
    </Signature>
</o:Security>
```

...you want to start with the `Reference` element, which points to the element with `id` "_0" (which in this case is the `Timestamp` element).  You then canonicalize the referenced element according to the nominated `Transform` algorithm.  That's most easily done by using [Apache XML Security](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.santuario/xmlsec), roughly like:

```
SOAPElement timestamp = secHeader.addChildElement(soapFactory.createName("Timestamp", "u", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"));
//[add 'Created' and 'Expires' values, as required]

//once you're done adding stuff, you can canonicalize the element
Canonicalizer canonizer = Canonicalizer.getInstance(Canonicalizer.ALGO_ID_C14N_EXCL_OMIT_COMMENTS);
byte[] canonTimestamp = canonizer.canonicalizeSubtree(timestamp);
```

That will give you something like this (newlines aren't canonical, sorry):

```
<u:Timestamp xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" u:Id="_0"><u:Created>2016-04-11T00:53:44.050Z</u:Created><u:Expires>2016-04-11T00:58:44.050Z</u:Expires></u:Timestamp>
```

Now you need to compute the `DigestValue` of that string.  The `DigestMethod` element in our `Reference` element tells us that this should be a SHA1 hash (base64-encoded).  So simply:

```
MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
String canonDigestValue = Base64.encodeBytes(sha1.digest(canonTimestamp));
```

The value that you get goes into the `Reference/DigestValue` element (assuming you're building an outbound request).  Once that is done, the `Reference` is complete, and since there aren't any additional `Reference` elements, so is the `SignedInfo` block.

Now to get the `SignatureValue`, you canonicalize the `SignedInfo` element, the same as before:

```
SOAPElement sigInfo = sigElem.addChildElement(new QName("SignedInfo"));
SOAPElement canon = sigInfo.addChildElement(new QName("CanonicalizationMethod"));
canon.addAttribute(soapFactory.createName("Algorithm"), Canonicalizer.ALGO_ID_C14N_EXCL_OMIT_COMMENTS);
//[continue adding the other elements...]

//canonicalize the entire, completed 'SignedInfo' block
byte[] bytesToSign = canonizer.canonicalizeSubtree(sigInfo);
```

Which should net you something like:

```
<SignedInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></CanonicalizationMethod><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#hmac-sha1"></SignatureMethod><Reference URI="#_0"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></Transform></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></DigestMethod><DigestValue>CwJgqLNOoHJpuiqIOylvVvFli1E=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo>
```

...and then you sign the whole thing according to the nominated `SignatureMethod` algorithm, which in our case is `HmacSHA1`:

```
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(getSharedKey(), "HmacSHA1");
mac.init(key);

String signature = Base64.encodeBytes(mac.doFinal(bytesToSign));
```

...where `getSharedKey()` returns, in this instance, a key derived using the `BinarySecret` values that the client and server sent during the initial `RequestSecurityToken` exchange.  As in:

```
private byte[] getSharedKey() {
    try {
        //XXX:  doesn't seem to be formally specified anywhere, but convention appears to be that the client key always goes first
        P_SHA1 algo = new P_SHA1();
        return algo.createKey(getBinaryClientEntropy(),  //the 'BinarySecret' value that the client sent to the server, decoded to raw binary 
                              getBinaryServerEntropy(),  //the 'BinarySecret' value that the server sent to the client, decoded to raw binary
                              0,                         //offset, '0' is what we want here
                              getSharedKeySize() / 8);   //'KeySize' is 256 bits in this case (specified by server), divide by '8' to convert to bytes
    }
    catch (Throwable e) {
        LOG.error("Unable to compute shared key!", e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Anyways, at this point you should have a signature value and it can be appended to the `Security` header in the outbound message, like:

```
SOAPElement sigValue = sigElem.addChildElement(new QName("SignatureValue"));
sigValue.addTextNode(signature);
```

And if all goes well, the message is now successfully signed and of acceptable quality for the server.

Though there was one final caveat that I noted, which is that the `Timestamp` values need to be generated in the server's timezone (which, in this case, is UTC), otherwise it will reject the request due to the timestamps either being from the future or having already expired.  A simple problem that could have been solved by standardizing on UNIX epoch timestamps.  But for some reason they went with "yyyy-mm-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.msec'Z'" instead.  Go figure.

I hope this is helpful to the next unfortunate soul who has to try to get Java talking to .NET using SOAP/XML.

And one final note if you're using Apache XML Security.  You need to call `org.apache.xml.security.Init.init()` before attempting to use the `Canonicalizer`, for instance from within a `static` initializer block.  If you don't, you'll get an exception (NPE I think it was) when you try to canonicalize.

Comment: Actually, the order of the entropies that are arguments to `P_SHA1` is specified formally by WS-Trust. In your particular case, the `ComputedKey` URI is `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/CK/PSHA1` which indicates the February 2005 revision of WS-Trust (http://specs.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/WS-Trust.pdf). From the spec: `The key is computed using P_SHA1 from the TLS specification to generate a bit stream using entropy from both sides. The exact form is: key = P_SHA1 (Ent_REQ, Ent_RES)`

Comment: I wish I could upvote this 1000x. You are a hero for following up with your findings here.

Comment: For anyone needing to do this in JavaScript, here's how you generate the signature: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55053741/5065447

Comment: I owe a lot to stackoverflow site, helped me uncountable times. But this question and this answer, so complete both, are simply the most amazing help I've come around in all this years in SO, and as I said, that's a lot. @aroth, as Jonathan said, I wish I could upvote this 1000 times, thanks you very much.